# Grails 2.3.4 War not correctly working in Tomcat 7.0.47

Tags: grails, tomcat7

Running the application with `grails run-app` works fine but after deploying in Tomcat 7 I get following error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: static com.digithurst.hdspro.web.Responder.respond() 
is applicable for argument types: (ResourceListCmd, QueryCmd, groovy.util.ConfigObject) 
values: [ResourceListCmd@5c380e, ...]
Possible solutions: respond(HttpResource, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
```

As already said, this works outside of Tomcat. The way the method is called is exactly as it is implemented. The `ResourceListCmd` implements the interface `HttpResource` which makes it a perfect fit. This error also occurs if the first parameter is `null`.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: static com.digithurst.hdspro.web.Responder.respond() 
is applicable for argument types: (null, QueryCmd, groovy.util.ConfigObject)
values: [null, ...]
Possible solutions: respond(HttpResource, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
```

More on the environment:

- Windows 7 64 Bit
- Java 7 U45 x86
- Grails 2.3.4
- Tomcat 7.0.47

I have already cleaned the `.grails` and `.m2` folders in the user directory and performed a `grails clean` berfore creating the war file.

[Edit after answer of H3rnst]

**Controller:**

```
def index() {

    try {
        ResourceListCmd configs = configService.search()
        respond Responder.respond(configs, new QueryCmd(level: 'list'),
                                  grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL)
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        render status: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    }
}
```

**ResourceListCmd:**

```
interface HttpResource {
    ...
}

abstract class AbstractHttpResource implements HttpResource {
    ...
}

class ResourceListCmd extends AbstractHttpResource {
    ...
}
```

**Responder**:

```
class Responder {
    static def respond(HttpResource resource, def query, String serverURL) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does run-war instead or run-app work?

Comment: I haven't tried `run-war` (didn't know that command) but, as written in the opening sentence, `run-app` does work.

Comment: I had a similar issue, run-app worked fine but run-war didn't work, can you give it a go?

Comment: I certainly can, but in what way will that help? This has to wait until Monday, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[marko's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023620/marko) suggestion doing `run-war` actually gave the final clue to solving this thing. It wasn't a problem with Tomcat but rather the environment the app was running in. `run-app` as well as `run-war` both use the "development" environment by default and therefore it worked. Only in "production" it did not, which is what is used when deployed to Tomcat.

The actual culprit was part of the configuration and the error message was right, although unexpected. I'm calling the `Responder.respond()` method with `grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL`. The `serverURL` was only set in "development" mode but not in "production". That's why Groovy/Java complained about the method signature:

```
(ResourceListCmd, QueryCmd, groovy.util.ConfigObject) vs (HttpResource, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
```

The clue is the last parameter, the first two are correct. However, I would've expected `null` as the value instead of a completely different type.

Answer (score 0):

Your war (or tomcat server classpath) contain a duplicate or wrong version of jar that contains the class com.digithurst.hdspro.web.Responder. (The version of the class you are using developing an launching with run-app is different from the one tomcat load running your war)

You could try to unpack the war end verify the version of the problematic jar and/or use a tool like [jarscan](https://java.net/projects/jarscan) to scan for duplicate classes.

You could even try to use the command [dependecy-report](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html) and search for duplicate injection of the same lib. Probably two different plugins your are using are incorporating to differente versions of the same lib causing the problem.

Comment: That class is written by me, so not part of any 3rd party lib. I will, however, have a look at what is inside the war.

Comment: Jarscan showed exactly one occurrence of `Responder`, being that one class that I wrote. I also used [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) to have a look at the `.class` and it is as expected.